# How does terminal read a file with a space in it?

Tags: terminal, cd

When I try to open a file that is say 'blue face' on my desktop my terminal won't recognize it. So if I don't want to drag and drop the file how do I use cd to call file 'blue face' the right way. I tried using an underscore like this 'cd blue_face' but still nothing. What's the right way to call a file with a space in it in terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either reference it with quotes:

```
cd "blue face"
```

Or by escaping the space with a backslash:

```
cd blue\ face
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use: cd 'blue face': the name of the file between single quotes.